# Entitymanager is null when inject by glassfish

Tags: ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, code-injection, gwt-rpc, entitymanager

****when i deploy project in glassfish entitymanager is null.if i use another thing instead of RPC like servlet project work probably***  *

session bean is:

```
@Stateless

public class logic implements logicLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="T2PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addToDB(Test t){

        em.persist(t);
    }

}
```

and GWT RPC is :

```
public class MainRPCImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MainRPC {

    @EJB
    logicLocal logic;


    @Override
    public String addToDB(Test t) {
        String m="fail";
        try {
            logic.addToDB(t);
            m="done successfuly";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return m;
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

persistence unit is :

```
  <persistence-unit name="T2PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>acm</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and glassfish-resources

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_acm_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="acm"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acm"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="acm" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_acm_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

specially thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are different reasons, but don't you need to use the jdbc context prefix for your JNDI name in persistence.xml? Something like this:

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/acm</jta-data-source>
```

From the [Glassfish administration guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggndp/index.html):

> A JDBC resource is created by specifying the connection pool with
>   which the resource will be associated . Use a unique Java Naming and
>   Directory Interface (JNDI) name to identify the resource. ... Because
>   all JNDI names are in the java:comp/env subcontext, when specifying
>   the JNDI name of a JDBC resource in the Administration Console, use
>   only the jdbc/name format.

Comment: thanks for your reply. when i use DTO and not use entity directly project work correctly, dou you have any idea to use from entity directly?